# How to calculate risk difference from a regression model in R?

Tags: r

I know how to calculate risk difference with a 2x2 table, but I have no idea how to do this with a regression model, even though it is a quite widely used method when you need to adjust variables in question.

In case I'm not making any sense, here's an article that discusses proper ways to calculate risk difference, but unfortunately it doesn't contain any code: https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-016-0217-0

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question, I think the book [Regression Modelling Strategies](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-19425-7) may be what you are looking for. For example:

```
# Load the rms Package by FE Harrell et al.,  remember to install the package first..
library(rms)

# Create a fit object using some dummy data in the package
fit <- npsurv(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml) 

# Then you can plot a Kaplan-Meier survival curve. 
plot(fit) 

# Then plot the 'Risk difference' for your data, with 95% confidence limits
survdiffplot(fit, xlim = c(0,60))
```